# Connecting to a remote MySQl server on cygwin

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I try connecting to a remote mysql server on `ip 10.198.161.41`

When I give

> mysql -u user -p -h 10.198.161.41

OUTPUT:

> Enter password: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '10.198.161.41' (111)

The mysqld on `10.198.161.41` runs on port `4308`.

Should it be mentioned in the command?

There is also no `my.cnf file in cygwin`.

What could I try?

```
(Info:The 10.198.161.41 is a windows machine and has mysqld running on it)
```

Comment: try with "mysql -u user -p -h 10.198.161.41 -P 4308"

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a million!! Could you give the reason?

Comment: actually mysql default port is 3306 and you are using here 4308, so you have to tell mysql on which port you want to connect with mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use mysql any different port than 3306 which is mysql default port then you must mention it to connect as per below-

```
mysql -u user -p -h 10.198.161.41 -P 4308
```

Here small p denotes to password and caps P to port.